# Random forest regressor has a negative score

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, model-evaluation, overfitting

I am using a RandomForestRegressor. When I check the score for the model with the training data, it's

Rregressor.score(X_train,y_train) 0.8357837327169805

but when I check the score using the test set, it's negative

Rregressor.score(X_validate,y_validate) -0.5022815681820925

Is this overfitting? Is this the right way to check how good a model is? What are the ways to improve the performance?

Comment: It can be overfitting or a mistake in data preparation logic.